# Stack call in Exception Handling

Tags: c#, exception

*According to the design guideline the catching exception should start from more specification exception to System.Exception.*

like :

```
try
{


}
catch(IOException IOEx)
{
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfRangeException AIE)
{
}
.....
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

I heard that CLR tracks the stack to trace the exception one by one to find the matching one(if an error occur). 
***As stack is "Last in first out" in nature won't CLR look in
reverse order ? ( i.e  Exception .. ArrayIndexOutOfRangeException .. IOException)***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - the stack in this case is the call stack, so if it doesn't find a handler in the current method, it will move up the stack to look for a handler. Within a particular method however, handlers are tested in the order they are specified.